# Join the strings from list for 4 set each

Tags: python, list

I have a list containing strings. I want to join the strings (four occurrence each) in index 0, 1, 2 respectively in a new list

```py
Old_List = [ 'User','need','to','log','in','Username','need','to','enter','in','Password','need','to','enter','here']
```

I want my list to look like this:

```py
New_list=['User need to log in', 'Username need to Enter in ', 'Password need to enter here']
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Since i am beginner i  am expecting someone who suggest me a answer and explain .thanks

Comment: four occurrence each as the expected list maybe you need Five not five!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be done by splitting a list into chunks by using *list-comprehension* and joining them back with `join` method.

```py
Old_List = ['User', 'need', 'to', 'log', 'in', 'Username', 'need',
            'to', 'enter', 'in', 'Password', 'need', 'to', 'enter', 'here']
Chunk_Size = 5
Newlist = [Old_List[sentenceStart:sentenceStart+Chunk_Size]
           for sentenceStart in range(0, len(Old_List), Chunk_Size)]

print([' '.join(sentence) for sentence in Newlist])
#    ['User need to log in', 'Username need to enter in', 'Password need to enter here']
```